# Read double from xml file with XMLReader

Tags: c#, .net, xml

I have a simple XML file created with XMLWriter using this code:

```
using (XmlWriter writer = XmlWriter.Create("c:\\temp\\data.xml"))
{

     writer.WriteStartElement("ScaleFactors");  

     writer.WriteStartAttribute("CorrectionFactorX");
     writer.WriteValue(CorrectionFactorX);
     writer.WriteEndAttribute();

     writer.WriteStartAttribute("CorrectionFactorY");
     writer.WriteValue(CorrectionFactorY);
     writer.WriteEndAttribute();

     writer.WriteStartAttribute("CorrectionFactorZ");
     writer.WriteValue(CorrectionFactorZ);
     writer.WriteEndAttribute();

     writer.WriteEndElement();

     writer.Flush();
}
```

XML file Looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <ScaleFactors CorrectionFactorX="1" 
                  CorrectionFactorY="1" 
                  CorrectionFactorZ="1" />
```

(CorrectionFactorX/Y/Z are doubles) Now I want to read them back with XMLReader but failed. I tried MoveToAttribute/GetAttribute with no success. Any hint and code example is appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you can use XDoc then

```
void Main()
{
    var xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><ScaleFactors CorrectionFactorX=\"1.31\" CorrectionFactorY=\"1\" CorrectionFactorZ=\"1\" />";
    var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(xml);

    var cfx = Double.Parse(xdoc.Element("ScaleFactors").Attribute("CorrectionFactorX").Value);
    Console.WriteLine (cfx);    
}
```

If you insist on using XmlReader, then

```
void Main()
        {
            var xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><ScaleFactors CorrectionFactorX=\"1.31\" CorrectionFactorY=\"1\" CorrectionFactorZ=\"1\" />";
            using (var reader = XmlReader.Create(new StringReader(xml)))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.NodeType == XmlNodeType.Element)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(reader.Name);
                        var attc = reader.AttributeCount;
                        for (int i = 0; i < attc; i++)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine(reader.GetAttribute(i));
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

(good example at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc189056(v=vs.95).aspx) on handling different parts of XML, but you're much better off with `XDocument`)

Comment: Had to use CultureInfo.InvariantCulture as second Parameter for Double.Parse. Otherwise it looked for an ',' as decimal point. Besided that it worked very well, thanks!

Comment: Don't use `Double.Parse()`, use [`XmlConvert.ToDouble(string)`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.xmlconvert.todouble%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).  It correctly handles internationalization.  Or use an explicit cast with [`XAttribute`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb338730%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) or [`XElement`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb303005%28v=vs.110%29.aspx).

Comment: Or, even better, there are built-in explicit conversions that use `XmlConvert` under the covers.  You can simply cast `XAttribute` or `XElement` to `double` or `double?`.

Answer (score 0):

using XmlDocument -

```
        var xml = new XmlDocument();
        xml.Load("xmlPath");

        var match = xml.DocumentElement.Attributes;
        foreach (XmlAttribute item in match)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(item.Value);
        }
```